# Did I anger my PI by not sending my data/notes after leaving their lab?

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

Last year I was informed by my PI that the lab was too busy to take on undergrad students. I said that I understood and found another lab that I was interested in to join.

However, I had been working on a project for a year before I left, and didn't get around to sending them any data/notes related to my project after I left. The lab members also didn't ask for any data. So, I'm not sure if maybe my project as a undergrad wasn't that important, or if I was unprofessional. Would it be late now, more than a year after I left, to send in data? Did I leave a bad impression?

I was hoping to ask the PI for letters of rec for grad school, but (1) He has new undergrad students now and I haven't spoken with him for a while and (2) I'm not sure if I left a bad impression when leaving the lab.

Answer (score 34):

So first, it seems a little strange that after an entire year of work, they would suddenly be "too busy to take on undergrad students." Of course I am only speculating, but my guess is that they (rightly or wrongly) didn't think your project was going anywhere and decided to cut you loose. This would also explain why they didn't ask for your data or notes, and why they have since hired new undergraduates. If this is the case, this PI would probably not be a good choice when asking for letters of recommendation.

At any rate, to your questions:

> I'm not sure if maybe my project as a undergrad wasn't that important, or if I was unprofessional.

If they wanted your data or notes, they should have asked for them. I assume there was no directive that you failed to follow, such as "upload your results to the portal every week." So no, I don't think it was unprofessional.

Why didn't they ask for your data or notes? Two possible reasons:

- In my experience, first-time undergraduate researchers do things *literally* hundreds of times slower than I can. So, I would likely start from scratch rather than trying to turn the student's product into something useable. Of course, this will vary by field -- I can imagine that some "wet labs" have very time-consuming processes for which undergraduate data would be valuable (if we trust the undergraduate).
- Everyone always has more ideas than they have time. If an idea gets consigned to an undergraduate, it's probably not very high-priority. So, it could be that no one is pursuing that idea, or that a new undergraduate will start from scratch on it.

> Would it be late now, more than a year after I left, to send in data?

Personally, I would not offer. As noted above, this is unlikely to be useful; further, it raises the question of "if you thought I needed this, why didn't you provide it a year ago?"

> I was hoping to ask the PI for letters of rec for grad school but I haven't spoken with him for a while and I'm not sure if I left a bad impression when leaving the lab

I wouldn't worry about not having spoken with him in a while -- everyone is busy. And I wouldn't worry about the data/notes situation. But I would think carefully about the circumstances under which you left the lab -- generally, we don't fire students if we think they deserve a very strong recommendation. But of course there are exceptions. You can certainly ask "Would you be able to write a strong recommendation?"

Answer (score 9):

If they did not ask for the data I would not be worried about sending the data. If the PI were interested, they would ask you for the data.

We cannot possibly know what the PI's impression of you. But if you were to ask for a recommendation letter, you should summarize your achievements in their lab and ask them if they could provide a "**strong**" recommendation letter in the email.

Answer (score 1):

The lab is obligated to keep records of its data, if that is reasonably feasible.  If you did not leave the data with the lab, you should make it available to the lab.

In my opinion, it is the supervisor's responsibility to ensure this is done.

This isn't likely to have a significant effect on letters of recommendation.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote; this is afaik mandatory in Germany. OP's PI probably does not care as explained in cag51's answer, but I see no harm in following best practices either. (although it would be pretty delayed here)